# Need the steps to create an MSSQL View/Table with only one column and one row that generates a Sequence ID, when I run a select query every time

Tags: sql-server, sql-view, sequence-generators

The below-mentioned are the Oracle SQL queries to generate the Sequence ID. Can anyone please help in rewriting the same queries compatible with MS SQL, to produce the same result?

1. DB Sequence: -

   ```
   create sequence my_sequence start with 1
   ```
2. Create a function get_next_code that will use the sequence and return the incremented value (as string): -

   ```
   create or replace function get_next_code return varchar2 as code number; 
   begin select my_sequence.nextval into code from dual; 
   return to_char(code); 
   end;
   ```
3. Create a view which will pass the incremented value: -

   ```
   create or replace view my_counter (my_code) as (select get_next_code() from dual);
   ```

Query used to get the sequence ID generated(This is the query used in the java program):

```
select my_code from my_counter
```

Expecting the same result in  MS SQL
Need the steps to create an MSSQL View/Table with only one column and one row that generates a Sequence ID, when I run a select query every time.

Comment: [so] isn't a translation service. Rather than dumping your Oracle code and expecting us to translate it, *explain* the problem you are trying to solve. A `VIEW`, in SQL Server, cannot be parametrised, so you *can't* pass the "incremented value" to one.

Comment: You also can't use `NEXT VALUE FOR` in a view, nor do I see how it would make sense to do so.

Comment: functions in sql server tend not to allow side-effect operations (like sequence incrementing) so you probably can't do it exactly the same. But you don't need a view for this in sql server, just read how sequences work, it's a simple select

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you create sequences in a similar way.

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE my_sequence START WITH 1;
```

Then to get the next value

```sql
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR my_sequence;
```

You can also use `sp_sequence_get_range` to get a range of numbers.